# Product categories are mixed when creating menu

Tags: menus, sub-menu, categories, menu-order

I created the product categories in woocommerce so cleanly,

[image]

And when im creating a new menu, its a mess. all are shuffled. Im using flatsome theme. WP-MegaMenu.

[image]

Please tell me a solution or a plugin which i can create a menu using my product categories.

Comment: Make a child theme and use `wp_list_pages()` instead. That way you don't have to manually mess with it.

Answer (score 0):

The first time you create a load of pages, or posts, or terms (whatever it may be) and then go to Menu, they won't ever be in the order you created them, don't know why but they're just not. You need to manually shuffle them around in the order you want and then save your menu but from then on it's fine.